# CMD instead of running command just opens it

Tags: google-app-engine, windows-7, python-2.7, cmd, command

OS Win7, GAE 1.7.6, Python 2.7.3

Working on Google app engine project with 2 other people, project leader gave us sample data via sampleData.cmd to run it inside.

```
nameOfTheApp\main>sampleData
```

On other 2 computer this command starts to download files, on my just returns.

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yam...etc
```

In other words it just pop up in my text editor, and in CMD, but it doesn't run it.
How to force this command to run?

EDIT: Open sampleData.cmd with editor and c/p content in CMD

```
python appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yam...etc
```

It returns python:can't open file 'appcfg.py' [Errno 2] No such file or directory

ANSWER:

Problem was that I associated .py files with my text editor, when changed to python.exe, it works...

Comment: Copy paste the command into CMD?

Comment: Exact same results...

Comment: I mean if you actually type in the command. What if you prepend `python` to the `appcfg.py` line?

Comment: Open sampleData.cmd with editor and c/p content in CMD
python appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yam...etc
It returns python:can't open file 'appcfg.py' [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Getting somewhere. Hold on.

Comment: What if you drop the `.py` and the `python`?

Comment: 'appcfg' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try using `python C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py` instead of raw `appcfg.py`.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine>python appcfg.py  I get ----------->        Usage: appcfg.py [options] <action>  Action must be one of: ...etc

Comment: Add the rest of your command.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/udKzjQrg

Comment: Problem was that I associated .py files with my text editor, when changed to python.exe, it works...

Comment: Me to...now using Google, to find out where it has been saved...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was that I associated .py files with my text editor, when i changed it to .exe, it works...